# Increase isolated storage size on windows phone from a different application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there a way of increasing the isolated storage size of a Windows Phone 8 application from another application or via settings on the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question begs another question of why exactly do you want to do it? Specifically what problem are you experiencing that makes you want to increase isolated storage?... Could your problem be solved by the answer provided in [this SO post about how to stream directly to isolated storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563753/windows-phone-isolatedstorage)

Namely look at the use of the following function:

```
IncreaseIsolatedStorageSpace(e.Result.Length)
```

And take a look [at this Windows 7 Phone solution](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=586)

```
protected bool IncreaseIsolatedStorageSpace(long quotaSizeDemand)
{
    bool CanSizeIncrease = false;
    IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    //Get the Available space
    long maxAvailableSpace = isolatedStorageFile.AvailableFreeSpace;

    if (quotaSizeDemand > maxAvailableSpace)
    {
        if (!isolatedStorageFile.IncreaseQuotaTo(isolatedStorageFile.Quota + quotaSizeDemand))
        {
            CanSizeIncrease = false;
            return CanSizeIncrease;
        }

        CanSizeIncrease = true;
        return CanSizeIncrease;
    }

    return CanSizeIncrease;
}
```

EDIT: Failing that, have a look into [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/), it's much better than the basic SDK

Answer (score 2):

Applications are sandboxed on Windows Phone
There is no way to increase isolated storage size from a different application.